# Executing program again, once finished (Python)

Tags: python, random, attributes, restart

So I'm writing this little piece of code as a small project: It uses the turtle graphics module to draw various shapes. It picks which shape to draw by way of the random module. Here's the code.

```
import time
import sys
import random
import os
from turtle import *

while True:
    value = 0
    def f():
    global value
    value = 1
onkey(f, "q")
listen()
random = random.choice('123456')
print(random)
if random == "1":
    #Star
    from turtle import *
    hideturtle()
    color('red', 'yellow')
    begin_fill()
    while True:
        forward(200)
        left(170)
        if abs(pos()) < 1:
            textinput("again1", "Again?")
            if textinput == "Yes"or"yes"or"Y"or"y":
                clearscreen()
                break
        if value == 1:
            textinput("again1", "Again?")
            if textinput == "Yes"or"yes"or"Y"or"y":
                clearscreen()
                break
    end_fill()
    done()
elif random == "2":
    #Extending Squares
    from turtle import *
    hideturtle()
    color('red', 'yellow')
    size=1
    begin_fill()
    while (True):
        forward(size)
        right(91)
        size = size + 1
        if value == 1:
            textinput("again2", "Again?")
            if textinput == "Yes"or"yes"or"Y"or"y":
                clearscreen()
                break
elif random == "3":
    #Extending Hexagons
    from turtle import *
    hideturtle()
    color('red','yellow')
    size=1
    while True:
        forward(size)
        right(61)
        size = size + 1
        if value == 1:
            textinput("again3", "Again?")
            if textinput == "Yes"or"yes"or"Y"or"y":
                clearscreen()
                break
elif random == "4":
    #Recursive Star
    import turtle
    from turtle import *
    def star(turtle, n,r):
     """ draw a star of n rays of length r"""
     for k in range(0,n):
        turtle.pendown()
        turtle.forward(r)
        turtle.penup()
        turtle.backward(r)
        turtle.left(360/n)

    def recursive_star(turtle, n, r, depth, f):
     """At each point of the star, draw another smaller star,
     and so on, up to given depth. Rescale the stars by a factor f
     at each generation."""
     if depth == 0:
        star(turtle, n, f*4)
     else:
        for k in range(0,n):
            turtle.pendown()
            turtle.forward(r)
            recursive_star(turtle, n, f*r, depth - 1,f)
            turtle.penup()
            turtle.backward(r)
            turtle.left(360/n)
            if value == 1:
                textinput("again4", "Again?")
                if textinput == "Yes"or"yes"or"Y"or"y":
                    clearscreen()
                    break

    fred = turtle.Turtle()
    fred.speed("fastest")
    fred.color('red','yellow')
    fred.hideturtle()
    recursive_star(fred, 5 , 150, 4, 0.4)
elif random == "5":
    #Honeycombs
    from turtle import *
    color('red','yellow')
    penup()
    setx(-200)
    sety(-150)
    pendown()
    side = 0
    side1 = 0
    begin_fill()
    while True:
        forward(50)
        right(60)
        side = side + 1
        side1 = side1 + 1
        if value == 1:
            textinput("again5", "Again?")
            if textinput == "Yes"or"yes"or"Y"or"y":
                clearscreen()
                break
        if side == 6:
            side = 0
            end_fill()
            begin_fill()
            while True:
                forward(50)
                left(60)
                side = side + 1
                side1 = side1 + 1
                if value == 1:
                    break
                if side == 6:
                    end_fill()
                    side = 0
                    forward(50)
                    left(60)
                    begin_fill()
                    break
        if side1 == 72:
             side1 = 0
             forward(50)
             left(60)
             forward(50)
             right(60)
elif random == "6":
    #Lattice of Squares
    color('red','yellow')
    while True:
        forward(200)
        right(91)
        forward(50)
        right(91)
        forward(50)
        right(91)
        if value == 1:
            textinput("again6", "Again?")
            if textinput == "Y"or"y"or"Yes"or"yes":
                clearscreen()
                break

else: sys.exit()
```

When the user presses "q" and asks the program to draw another shape, I want the program to go back to the top of the very outermost while loop. I'm using break to do this and it works fine. However, I run into trouble when it gets to:

```
random = random.choice('123456')
```

The program gives me an error, saying:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\aerro_000\Desktop\PrettyShapes.py", line 14, in <module>
random = random.choice('123456')
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'choice'
```

How do I fix this? Or is there a way to just restart the entire program? I've also tried using random.randint but I get a similar error.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You're relying on `random` to be the `random` module, which has a function `choice`. The first time you call it, you assign its result, one of the characters in `'123456'`, to the name `random`, thus making the name `random` no longer point to the `random` module. Use a different name, like `random_number = random.choice('123456')`, instead.

Answer (score 0):

The first time you launch your program, you set your `random` variable with `random.choice()` it work because the variable `random` isn't created before you call `random.choice()`. However, the seconde time, your variable `random` is a string and when you try to change the value of `random` with `random.choice` it can't work because python thinks you are trying to call `choice()` on your `random` variable and that you are not actualy using the "random library".

So you just need to rename your varibale `random` with something else.

For exemple, this will work:

```
import random
random1 = random.choice('123456')
print (random1)
random1 = random.choice('123456')
print(random1)
```

But not that:

```
import random
random = random.choice('123456')
print (random)
random = random.choice('123456')
print(random)
```